# Сжимаемость модального окна

Tags: html, css

Возникла проблема: решил создать модальное окно так, чтобы оно могло сжиматься при уменьшении размеров экрана. Пытался найти какое-то решение и вроде как нашел рабочий вариант с заданием обычных габаритов и максимальных = 100%, но у меня почему-то это не срабатывает, подскажите в чем ошибка

```
.pass-change {
display: none;
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
overflow: auto;
z-index: 995;

}
.modal-overlay{
z-index: 990;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
display: none;
}
.pass-change-content {
background-color: #fff;
width: 600px;
max-width: 100%;
height: 350px;
max-height: 100%;
padding: 15px;
margin: 10% auto;
z-index: 1000;
}


var modal = document.getElementById('modal-pass-change');
var btn = document.getElementById("pass-change");
var img = document.getElementById("cross-pass-change");
var bcg = document.getElementById("modal-overlay")

btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
bcg.style.display = "block";
}

img.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
bcg.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
modal.style.display = "none";
bcg.style.display = "none";
}
}

<button id="pass-change" class="graybutton">Изменить пароль</button>
    

    <div id="modal-pass-change" class="pass-change" style="display: none;">
        <div class="pass-change-content">
            <div class="cross" id="cross-pass-change"></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus itaque, aperiam iusto, facilis quibusdam eligendi? A fuga sequi maiores velit quas incidunt illo repellendus enim?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-overlay" id="modal-overlay" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: указывайте в vw а внутренний в процентах

Answer (score 1):

Для блока `.pass-change`:

```
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
```

А также, чтобы выровнять окно по вертикали:

```
transform: translate(-50%, calc(-50% - 50px));
```

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('modal-pass-change');
var btn = document.getElementById("pass-change");
var img = document.getElementById("cross-pass-change");
var bcg = document.getElementById("modal-overlay")

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  bcg.style.display = "block";
}

img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  bcg.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    bcg.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.pass-change {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, calc(-50% - 50px));
  z-index: 995;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
}

.modal-overlay {
  z-index: 990;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  display: none;
}

.pass-change-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 10% auto;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<button id="pass-change" class="graybutton">Изменить пароль</button>

<div id="modal-pass-change" class="pass-change" style="display: none;">
  <div class="pass-change-content">
    <div class="cross" id="cross-pass-change"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus itaque, aperiam iusto, facilis quibusdam eligendi? A fuga sequi maiores velit quas incidunt illo repellendus enim?</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-overlay" id="modal-overlay" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Открывайте на всю страницу и меняйте ширину окна.

Comment: а если я хочу чтобы окно было не размером по содержимому, а фиксированного размера или меньше фиксированного размера, если окно маленькое?